# Conditions for the Following Series to Converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, cauchy-product

The problem is to show on which conditions the following series converge
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left({\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^k}{(-1)^{(n-k)+1}\frac{(n-k)^2}{e^{n-k}}}
\right)
$$
I tried to simplify the series by writing their Cauchy product as
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left({\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^k}{(-1)^{(n-k)+1}\frac{(n-k)^2}{e^{n-k}}}
\right) \leq \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n  \right) \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{(n+1)}\frac{(n)^2}{e^{n}}  \right)
$$
However, first I need to prove both series converge absolutely. The series on the left-hand converge absolutely if $|a|<1$ , but I do not know on which conditions the second one also converge absolutely. So my question is to find the conditions in which the following series converge absolutely
$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{(n+1)}\frac{(n)^2}{e^{n}}  \right)
$$

Comment: The last series is a variant of the geometric series   $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n+1} e^{-n} n^2=\frac{(e-1) e}{(1+e)^3}$$

Comment: Thank you, however I need to show that this series converge absolutely, in other means, I should prove that its absolute components converge